# Grabbing the most recent log file from multiple computers (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I want to create a script that will access computers on a .txt file and grab the latest log file from each and output the file and computer name into a new document. I've searched around feel confident that I can achieve this by combining the following two examples in some way, but I'm not entirely sure how.
To get files from the same location on multiple computers:

```
$Computers = get-content "C:\Computers.txt"
$OutFile = "C:\Results.txt"

#Erase an existing output file so as not to duplicate data
out-file -filepath $OutFile

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{

if (test-path \\$computer\c$\temp\logfile.txt)  #test to make sure the file 
exists
{
#Get the CreationTime value from the file
$FileDate = (Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\temp\logfile.txt).CreationTime

#Write the computer name and File date separated by a unique character you 
can open in Excel easy with"
"$Computer | $FileDate" | out-file -FilePath $OutFile -Append -Encoding 
ascii
}
else
{
#File did not exist, write that to the log also
"$Computer | FILE NOT FOUND" | out-file -FilePath $OutFile -Append -Encoding 
ascii
}
}
```

To get the latest file in a directory

```
$dir = "C:\test_code"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending 
| Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- erase the output file; but you can just overwrite it.
- put everything in variables; but you only use them once.
- make up your own pipe delimited CSV with double output handling and encoding weirdness, PS has pretty good CSV handling.
- no need to test if file exists, since you don't know what it will be called.

e.g.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Computers.txt" | ForEach-Object {    # Each computer

    # Get latest file
    $Latest = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$_\c$\temp\*" | 
                  Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending |
                  Select-Object -First 1

    # Make a custom object with the three things to go in the output CSV
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Computer     = $_
        FileName     = if ($latest) { $Latest.Name }         else { "File not found" }
        CreationTime = if ($latest) { $Latest.CreationTime } else { "n/a" }
    }

} | Export-Csv c:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII  # write the output csv
```